# Inflate image on top of a popupview object

Tags: android, popupwindow

Currently for inflating images (zoom in animation) we use this [library](https://github.com/code-crusher/Image-Zoomer).
while on top of regular activities it looks fine (Simple layout), on top of a popupview the image is "behind" the popup.

[image]
Tried to change the elevation parameters, but no luck there either.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    tools:context="com.MapActivity">




    <com.vatsal.imagezoomer.ImageZoomButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_picture"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/tx_description"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bt_date_time"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-25dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_picture" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is how the popupview and windows are inflated:

```
popupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.job, null);
popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
                              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
```

Should we try and use a different approach? Mabye ditch the library and inflate it differently?
Thanks

Comment: You can use simple dialog for this, not necessary to use extra libraries and it is more efficient.   just provide layout for your dialog and show it on action.

Answer (score 0):

We've followed mmdreza's advice, here's a snippet of the implementation.
As the documantation states, the alertdialog will be on top of the popupview object.

```
myHolder.jobImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());

                    LayoutInflater inflater =
                            (LayoutInflater)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflated_picture_dialog, null);
                    Picasso.get().load(jobView.getJobImageURL()).fit().into(((ImageButton)mView.findViewById(R.id.inflated_picture)));

                    mBuilder.setView(mView);
                    final AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
                    dialog.show();

                }
            });
```